# How to group values based on a "connectedness" metric?

Tags: linux, shell-script, perl

There is a file with three columns.
Columns 1 and 2 contain numbers drawn from the same set.
The file will typically have one line for each pair of members of the set;
so, if there are *n* members,
there should be *n*×(*n*−1)/2 lines.

Column 3 shows the amount of connectedness between numbers in columns 1 and 2.

I want to partition my source set into groups of consecutive values
(i.e., ranges) for which connectedness is greater than or equal to 0.2. 
For example, in this small data set:

input:

```
1   2       0.222
1   3       0.213
1   4       0.014
1   5       0.001
1   6       0.555
1   7       0.509
2   3       0.213
2   4       0.014
2   5       0.001
2   6       0.555
2   7       0.709
2   8       0.509
3   4       0.995
3   5       0.323
3   6       0.555
3   7       0.225
3   8       0.001
4   5       0.095
4   6       0.058
4   7       0.335
4   8       0.005
5   6       0.995
5   7       0.658
5   8       0.650
6   7       0.431
6   8       0.333
7   8       0.754
```

the output should be like:

output:

```
   G1: 1 2 3    G2: 4   G3 :5 6 7 8
```

Connectedness between 1 with 2 and 3, is greater than 0.2, so 1, 2 and 3  should be placed in  first group. In fact, any pair of numbers within a group must have enough connectedness together. Despite high relation between 1/2/3 and 6 (0.555 > 0.2), 6 should not be placed in the first group, since previous numbers (4 and 5) had low connectedness with 1. So we must not jump over 4 and 5 and connect numbers in the first group with 6.

Number 4 does not have the high connectedness with 5, so number 4 should be in the second group individually. No matter that 4 has a high connectedness with 7 since the previous numbers (5 and 6) were in low connectedness with 4 and we must not jump over numbers in between and connect 4 with 7.

5 has a high connectedness with 6, 7 and 8. Also, any pair of numbers (like 6/7, 6/8, 7/8) have high connectedness together.
Therefore they should be placed together in the third group.
That is why all of these numbers can be placed in one group.

Note that the real data does not begin from number 1 and there are over 100,000 lines. so it is huge.

here is a part of my real data:
input:

```
    49997 49998 0.082
    49997 49999 0.953
    49997 50000 0.060
    49998 49999 0.288
    49998 50000 0.288
    49999 50000 0.265
```

output should be:

```
  G1:49997   G3: 49998 49999 50000
```

Comment: Why do `1 2 3` form a group, when `2` and `3` are connected weakly with `0.001`?

Comment: @choroba for now this is not a matter of point. but if connectedness between 2 and 3 should obey the threshold, then how the program that you wrote should be changed? could you show me in both cases please?

Comment: I'm trying to interpret your explanation and can't figure out why `7` is not in groups `1` and `2`.  in both cases, 7 has connectedness > 0.2 AND come immediately after another number (`6`) which also has high connectedness.  could you explain what it is that excludes 7 from your required output?  also, are the group numbers supposed to be sequential (1,2,3, etc) or are they supposed to be equal to the first field?  what output do you expect from the real data sample your provided?

Comment: It's not clean question, Please edit it.

Comment: @cas the reason is that the numbers before 7 (4,5 and 6) are not in enough connectedness with number 1. for the same reason number 7 can not be placed in gruop2. because numbers between 4 and 7 ( 5 and 6 ) are not in good connectedness with number 4.

Comment: ok.  there are still at least two things that unclear: 1. why does `G2=(4)` when there aren't three other groups containing only 2, 3, and 6 - what's different about 4 that it gets its own group but the others don't? 2. why is `G3=(5,6,7)` rather than `G3=(3,4,5,6)` and `G4=(5,6,7)`?

Comment: 1. the differen with 4 is that 4 does not have enough connectedness by immediate next number(5). 2. because 3 has enough connectedness with 1, it is already placed in the first group. note that 3 or any number can not be appeared in more than one group. 4 can not be with 3 beacuse , 3 is already well connected in first gruop, while 4 is not well-connected with number 1. ok. I gonna edit the whole question as it is not possible to delte it.

Comment: I think the question is at least understandable after the edit, but this seems more about graph theory or finding non-zero submatrices from a large matrix, instead of anything to really do with Unix-like systems.

Comment: Why is there a group for 1 and 3, when a number before 3 (i.e. 2) has a low connectedness?

Comment: The only way I can make sense of your explanation, I get `G1: 1 2 3 G3: 4 5 6 7 G5: 8` for the first set of input and `G1: 49997 G2: 49998 49999 50000`

Comment: @choroba - you seem to be able to understand his explanation - can you explain it in some logical fashion....this is driving me nuts.  he keeps changing the explanation, (and the sample data) but the output he wants seems to be different to what his explanation says.   and his Q on SO doesn't make it any clearer (e.g. my interpretation (using a HoA rathar than AoA) of the expl. there gets `G1: 1 3   G2: 4 5 6 7` rather than the `G1: 1 3    G2: 4   G3 :5 6 7` he expects).

Comment: @cas: I was confused at the beginning, too. I still can't understand the algorithm in a declarative way, but as a sequence of steps: read a line, if possible, add to a group, if not, keep skipping lines until you get to processing the number you weren't able to add.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the input. While the first number is the same and connectedness is over the threshold, add numbers to the same group. Once the connectedness is too low, do nothing until you meet the second number in the first column.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $THRESHOLD = 0.2;

my $next;
my @groups;
while (<>) {
    my ($n1, $n2, $connectedness) = split;
    @groups = ([ $next = $n1 ]) unless defined $next;
    if ($next == $n1) {
        if ($connectedness > $THRESHOLD) {
            push @{ $groups[-1] }, $n1 unless @{ $groups[-1] };
            push @{ $groups[-1] }, $n2;

        } else {
            $next = $n2;
            push @groups, [$n2];
        }
    }
}

for my $i (1 .. @groups) {
    print "Group $i: @{ $groups[ $i - 1 ] }\n";
}
```

Comment: this script works perfectly for the small example, but in my real data it does not work and it gives an empty. could the reason be that in my real data, numbers do not begin from 1? or could the reason be that ma real data is space deliminator ? I put a part of my real data in  my question to make it clear. Can you guide me?

Comment: @zara, choroba's script works for me with the data you provided.  btw, perl's split function uses any amount of white-space as field separator by default (i.e. 1 or more spaces or tabs).  is your data from a windows machine (i.e. with CRLF line terminators rather than unix-style LF only)?

Comment: @cas no my data is in sever, I am runing in linux, I put a part of my real data in my question. if you run this on that you will see it does not work

Comment: i posted that comment before i saw your "real data" extract.  i'll have another look.

Comment: @zara: Yes, initialize `$next` to the real starting number.

Comment: @zara: or use the updated script which initializes it automatically.

Comment: @zara: The current version of choroba's answer works for both of your data sets.  Why should he (or anybody) take another look at your question?

Comment: @G-Man because if a number be missing in first column, then program stop from that missing number. for example here number 2 is missing. if you run the program you will see it does not work from missing number.

Comment: @choroba can you please take another look to the question?if a number be missing in first column, then program stop from that missing number. for example here number 2 is missing. if you run the program you will see it does not work from missing number.

Comment: Please, use a new question to ask a new question. Also, try to understand my code, only a small change might be needed to make it work for the updated input.

Comment: @choroba ok i am plying with your code. also I put a new question

Comment: @zara: You say you’ve asked a new question, but I don’t see it.  You’ve ***edited*** your existing question twice since I edited it, and, as far as I can tell, your most recent edit pretty much cancelled out the previous one (but left the question less clear).  Are your data complete or aren’t they?  (I.e., is it possible that a number that appears in the second column doesn’t appear in the first column?)

Comment: @G-Man: http://stackoverflow.com/q/38857695/1030675

Comment: @G-Man I put the new question which is already answered too. I do not know why you can not see.